# Asp.net core MVC disable lot of elements on client computer without contacting server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hey I have a lot of elemetns. When I push button it will check what background color is and then based on that disable or enable a lot of elements. Some idea? I personaly dont know where to start. Thanks for any help. Also I need it to execute on users computer so I dont need to contact server. I was wandering if JavaScript can do it well, but I dont want to assing all elements seperately so maybe assing class or something.

Comment: If you want to make change to multiple elements in the HTML, you need to use JQuery. That will allow you to select elements based on various criteria and change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to build a simple code, which works at client-side.
With the help of proper selector you can modify multiple elements with single line of code.

Below example will enable/ disable inputs with background color as 'blue' on click of a button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.blueCss{
  background-color: blue;
}
.greenCss{
  background-color: green;
}
.redCss{
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnEnable").click(function(){    
    // below line enables all input elements with class blueCss
    $("input.blueCss").removeAttr('disabled');
  });
  
  $("#btnDisable").click(function(){    
    // below line disables all input elements with class blueCss
    $("input.blueCss").attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
  
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <input type="text" class="blueCss" value="First"> <br>
 <input type="text" class="greenCss" value="Second"> <br>
 <input type="text" class="greenCss" value="Third"> <br>
 <input type="text" class="blueCss" value="Fourth"> <br>
 <input type="text" class="redCss" value="Fifth"> <br>
 
<input type="Button" id="btnDisable" value="Disable Blue"> 
<input type="Button" id="btnEnable" value="Enable Blue"> <br>



</body>
</html>
```